# "HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http" in PHP

Tags: php

I want to say thanks for your support in advance. I am trying to consume a web service which written in ASP.Net using PHP. When I run the code i got this error :-
HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://office-server/tempPlace/Service.asmx, Error (10272051):

Can anyone help me out thanks, this is the code that i wrote:

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.aaa.org/tempPlace/Service.asmx?wsdl','wsdl');
$err = $client->getError(); 

if($err){ 
    echo $err; 
} 

$params = array('userName' ='edit', 'password' = 'edit'); 
$result = $client->call('GetLastVersion',$params); 

if ($client->fault) { 
    echo 'Fault'. print_r($result); 
} else { 
    // Check for errors 
    $err = $client->getError(); 
    if ($err) { 
        // Display the error 
        echo 'Error'. $err; 
    } else { 
        // Display the result 
        echo 'Result' . print_r($result);       
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: hi thanks but i could access the ASP.Net web service using C# and VB.net why won't work in PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[You already asked this question](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/226845/HTTP-Error-HTTP-Error-Couldnt-open-socket-connecti)

> your code looks fine to me, the problem could be in your network settings, check your firewall and antivirus settings.

Comment: hi thanks but i could access the ASP.Net web service using C# and VB.net why won't work in PHP

Answer (score 0):

the function `fsockopen` is forbidden by in your `php.ini`.